# Is there any way to group input fields in win forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

For example if I want to check if all the input fields are filled, I do not want to do this with a lot of if statements, especially if there are a lot of text fields. So is there a better way?

Comment: How would you know which fields to check, if not by mentioning which fields you want to have checked? What research have you done in regards to input/form validation? Also, without an attempt from you to fix this, this is not a valid question for StackOverflow.

Comment: To 'group' them you need to mark them somehow as being part of a group. You can do it in many ways: Adding it to a common container; giving it a certain name pattern; using their Tag; collect them in a list. Then you can use loops like the ones in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about looping through all controls in the form, and get if it's empty or not ?

```
foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
    {
      if(control is TextBox && control.Text == "")
         {
            MessageBox.Show("You have to fill all fields");
             return;
         }
    }
```

sure you can check for whatever control you want ! not just the textBoxes

Answer (score 2):

With [System.Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq(v=vs.110).aspx) you can do it in one line, and filter it on the controls you need:

```
 this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().All(box => box.Text.Length > 0);
```

Or for checkbox

```
this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().All(box => box.Checked);
```

And so on.

It will return true if all is filled/checked.

Just remember to put using System.Linq; on top of your code